# How to write if else to get value from edit text android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, android-edittext

I have this 3 types of edit text input.

I want to compare the 3 edit text to get the `FreeTime`.

xml codes

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="@string/morningLabel"
    android:id="@+id/MorningLabel"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/MorningText"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/MorningText" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Working Hour(s)"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Afternoon"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Evening"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/AfternoonText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=" 6.01 a.m. \n       to \n12.00 p.m."
    android:id="@+id/morningTime"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=" 12.01 p.m. \n       to \n 6.00 p.m."
    android:id="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/morningTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text=" 6.01 p.m. \n       to \n12.00 a.m."
    android:id="@+id/eveningTime"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/EveningText"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/EveningText" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Result"
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="38dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/eveningTime"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/eveningTime"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/morningTime"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/morningTime"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/MorningText"
    android:hint="0-6"
    android:layout_marginBottom="22dp"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:background="#ffd1d1d1"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material"
    android:layout_above="@+id/morningTime"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/morningTime"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/morningTime"
    android:text="@string/MorningInput"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/AfternoonText"
    android:hint="0-6"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:background="#ffd1d1d1"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/MorningText"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:text="@string/AfternoonInput"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:numeric="integer" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/EveningText"
    android:hint="0-6"
    android:autoText="true"
    android:background="#ffd1d1d1"
    android:editable="false"
    android:textSize="@dimen/abc_text_size_display_1_material"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/AfternoonText"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/AfternoonText"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView5"
    android:text="@string/EveningInput"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:numeric="integer"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView5" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/timeLabel"
    android:id="@+id/TimeText"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNext" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="c"
    android:onClick="calculateClickHandler"
    android:id="@+id/btnc"
    android:layout_above="@+id/TimeText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/afternoonTime"
    android:layout_marginBottom="42dp" />
```

This is the java code. I think I put the wrong if else. How can I solve this? Anyone help:

```
public class WorkingHour extends Activity
{

public void calculateClickHandler(View view)
{

    if (view.getId() == R.id.btnc)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this, Result.class);

        // get the references to the widgets
        EditText MorningInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.MorningText);
        EditText AfternoonInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.AfternoonText);
        EditText EveningInput = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.EveningText);
        TextView TimeText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TimeText);

        // get the users values from the widget references
        int morninghour = Integer.parseInt(MorningInput.getText().toString());
        int afternoonhour = Integer.parseInt(AfternoonInput.getText().toString());
        int eveninghour = Integer.parseInt(EveningInput.getText().toString());

        // calculate the free time
        int freeTimeValue = calculateFreeTime(morninghour,afternoonhour,eveninghour);

        // interpret the meaning of the bmi value
        String freetimeInterpretation = interpretFT(freeTimeValue);

        // now set the value in the result text
        TimeText.setText(freeTimeValue + "-" + freetimeInterpretation);

        SharedPreferences sp2 = getSharedPreferences("name2",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sp2.edit();
        editor.putString("rslt 3",TimeText.getText().toString());
        editor.commit();
    }
}

// the formula to calculate the free time
private int calculateFreeTime (int morninghour, int afternoonhour, int eveninghour)
{
    if (((6- morninghour)> (6-afternoonhour)) && ((6- morninghour)> (6-eveninghour)))
    {
        return (int) (6 - morninghour);
    }
    else if (((6- afternoonhour)> (6-morninghour)) && ((6- afternoonhour)> (6-eveninghour)))
    {
        return (int) (6 - afternoonhour);
    }
    else if (((6- eveninghour)> (6-morninghour)) && ((6-eveninghour)> (6-afternoonhour)))
    {
        return (int) (6 - eveninghour);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
if (freetime < )
{
    return "morning";
}
```

Is definitely wrong and should not even compile. You are saying here: if `freetime` is smaller than nothing... do something. You have to put a value in it (these are for example):

```
if (freetime < 6)
{
    return "morning";
}
else if (freetime < 12)
{
    return "Afternoon";
}
```

Also, there is no need to cast this return value because it are both integers:

```
return (int) (6 - morninghour);
       ^^
```

If you want to make your code a little better (mainly for readability), you can optimize this:

```
morninghour   = 6 - morninghour;
afternoonhour = 6 - afternoonhour;
eveninghour   = 6 - eveninghour;

if ((morninghour > afternoonhour) && (morninghour >  eveninghour))
{
    return morninghour;
}
else if ((afternoonhour > morninghour) && (afternoonhour > eveninghour))
{
    return afternoonhour;
}
else if ((eveninghour > morninghour) && (eveninghour > afternoonhour))
{
    return eveninghour;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: If user enter the 3 edit text, then compare which is the higher value so that the freeTime will be the highest value. The max input for each edit text is 6. because of that (6-morning),(6-afternoon),(6-evening) then compare it.

Comment: @Sekdahai So the user cannot input a value higher than 6? Or can they and you need to check?

Comment: @Sekdahai because if they can, you can just check: `if(morninghour > 6 && afternoonhour > 6 && eveninghour > 6){ /*error*/}else{/*calculate highest*/}`

Comment: Morning free time left = (6-morninghour)<br/> Afternoon free time left = (6-afternoonhour) <br/> Evening free time left = (6-eveninghour)<br/><br/>

Comment: Freetimeleft = if ((morning free time left)> (Afternoon free time left)) AND  ((morning free time left)> (Evening free time left)) then I will choose Morning Free Time.

Comment: else if((Afternoon free time left)> ( morning free time left)) AND  ((Afternoon free time left)> (Evening free time left)) then I will choose Afternoon Free Time.

Comment: else if((Evening free time left)> ( morning free time left)) AND  ((Evening free time left)> (Afternoon free time left)) then I will choose Evening Free Time.